# After bean definition created from @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

The problem:

I have a bean (`ConversionService`) that needs a collection of `Converter`s to be created. So within my `@Configuration` class I have a `@Bean` that is a `Collection<Converter>` with a specific `@Qualifier`.

For my `ConversionService` `@Bean`, I receive the `Converter` collection as parameter using my `@Qualifier` like this:

```
@Bean
public ConversionService createConversionService(@Qualifier("converters") converters) {
    // here I perform the ConversionService creation
}
```

This works and is exactly how I want it. But I have several `@Configuration` classes, and each one shall be able to add something to the `Converter` collection. I initially though maybe there is a way to implement a method invoked after bean definition is read from `@Configuration` class. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("converters")
    private Collection<Converter> converters;

    public void init() {
        converters.add(xy);
    }

}
```

or even

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    public void init(@Qualifier("converters") Collection<Converter> converters) {
        converters.add(xy);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add something to your `converters` in your `@Configuration` annotated class using the [`@PostConstruct`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("converters")
    private Collection<Converter> converters;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        converters.add(xy);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using just spring classes? @PostConstruct is a javax annotation.

Comment: perfect, I got it implementing org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean Thanks for your help Alex!

Comment: @JavaMentor : can you post your answer?

Comment: @NandkumarTekale: I solved it implementing something like:
`@Configuration public class CoreConfiguration implements InitializingBean {`, the approach is very much like my first example of `@Configuration` class, but instead of method `init` I shall implement `public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {`. This answer solved the problem using `javax.annotation`, and in fact will have the same result.